# Is there a simple and clean way to bind a form input to two attributes on the domain class?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, binding

Imagine you have a class that has two attributes and they're always going to be set to the same initial value, (e.g. "bla bla" on both attributes). Since spring does all the hard work on binding the inputs' values to the domain class, I've been wondering if there is a way to bind the same value from the form on both attributes.

(I know that I could just set the value of the second equal to the first on the controller but that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid)

Consider the following code as an illustration of what I'm trying to explain:

```
class X {
   private String value;
   private String secondValue

   ... getters and setters ...
}
```

```html
<form >
   <input name="value/secondValue" />

   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I expect to have both attributes set after springs does its magic.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a JavaScript library like jQuery use an event like change and set the other hidden input pointing to the second variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="secondValue" value="" />


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#value').change(function() {
        $('#secondValue').val($('#value').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I understand that this is a possibility, but, as I said, I want to know if there is a clean way to do it using a spring configuration or something like that. And, as far as I've looked into this problem, using JS is not the cleanest approach at all.